# How to stop Kentico Event Log from getting huge?

Tags: azure, kentico, event-log

Just checked my Kentico database (Azure hosting) and it ballooned to 21GB. This happened fairly recently since 4 months ago it was just a bit above 1GB.

Checked the tables and my Event Log table has over 2,000,000 entries!!!

Nothing has changed recently, my settings under Settings -> System -> Event Log are still the same:

Event Log Size: 1000

Since globals are also set to 1000, usually I have 2000 or so entries in the event log table.

Anyone knows what happened here? And how to stop it from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have online marketing turned on and have a popular site, there will be lots of data in the OM_ tables. But still 20GB sounds huge, are there lots of asset files been added to the Content Tree, like videos? Also, is the database set to log all transactions? What kind of log files are popular? Errors or Information logs? Do you have some custom code that could produce lots of logs?

You can also email Kentico support to get a "check big tables" SQL script which can help you find out which are the large tables.

Comment: Rui, nothing like that, videos and all the media is stored in file system. Nothing really changed recently EXCEPT we upgraded to Kentico 12. And since the logs are huge, I am not even able to access them through Kentico - it times out on me. We also have a staging site which has the exact same data - and the DB is only 1.5GB.

Comment: An my question is why is the event log so huge? I thought Kentico was supposed to keep only 2000 or so newest log entries? Why is it keeping 2,000,000 of them?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the database before the upgrade? How many events logs were in there? Did something happen during the upgrade that the logs just jumped to a huge number that now the task for deleting old logs is having hard time process the data (e.g. time out) so the logs is just keep growing?

Comment: Rui, nothing out of ordinary happened during the upgrade. Right after the upgrade (12/21/2018), the EventLog had 2132 events. The next backup I have was about a month and a half after the upgrade (2/11/2019) EventLog had  2075 records. Now (3/13/2019), over 2 million. So it does seem that lately they are not being deleted for some reason.

Comment: Can I just go to query editor in Azure and delete records or truncate the dbo.CMS_EventLog table? I am assuming this would not mess up Kentico in any way?

Comment: You can also use your local MS SQL Mgn Studio to connect to the Azure database. You can find the credential in your Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into a few other areas as well.  Having 2MM event log records won't cause a 20GB jump in DB size from a Kentico perspective as the event logs are pretty minimal data.

Take a look in the analytics, version history, email queue, web farm and scheduled task tables.  Also check out the recycle bin.  Are you integrating with any other system or inserting/updating a lot of data via the API?  If so, this could cause a lot of transactional log files to build up. With Azure SQL I don't know of a way to clean those up.

My suggestion is to check other tables and not just the event log.  Maybe query the event log manually via SSMS and see what the top 100 events are and that might help you find the problem.  If you need to you could probably clear the log too either through the UI or manually truncate the table using SSMS.

Comment: Well, I imported DB to my local machine and when I check the CMS_EventLog table with SSMS it tells me that the data space for this one table is 20,773.461 MB - so it seems that this table did increase the DB size for about 20GB. I understand that I can clear it, but first why and how did this happen and how to stop it from happening again?

Comment: As I mentioned before, Kentico was supposed to purge older records and keep the most 2000 of them, not 2 million.

Comment: I'd dig into the event log and look at the errors/events in there.  If it can't process the event log to clear it out because of size, it will fail and keep adding records to it.  So it's an issue with the processing on the table from Kentico's side since there is too many records and not enough horsepower to process it.

Comment: Can I just go to query editor in Azure and delete records or truncate the dbo.CMS_EventLog table? I am assuming this would not mess up Kentico in any way?

Comment: I've never used the query editor in Azure so can't speak to the performance of it.  But yes, you can truncate the table without any negative impact on "messing up Kentico".

Comment: Any suggestion how to stop this from happening? Where do I even look? For the time being I switched from log to database to log to file system but my log file is getting big as well.

Comment: I would monitor the event log, if it gets over 2000 (with setting set to 1000), then there is something else going wrong.

Comment: @elveez query the event log and see what the events are.  `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM CMS_EventLog ORDER BY EventTime DESC`  You can then look at the details of the errors from there to find out what's going on.